# How do I change where the page number is located when rendering a pdf?

Tags: asciidoctor, asciidoctor-fopub

I am using [asciidoctor-fopub](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-fopub) to generate a pdf from an asciidoc.

The page number is added in the middle of the page footer. I would like to move it to the far right. I am convinced that this is doable. But I can't find any example of how to customize the page footer properly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have asciidoc files it might be easier to use [asciidoctor-pdf](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoctor-pdf/) directly. With asciidoctor-pdf it is possible to design your own footer with [themes](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/blob/master/docs/theming-guide.adoc#keys-running-content). How to apply themes is described [here](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/blob/master/docs/theming-guide.adoc).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use asciidoctor-pdf as it doesn't handle footnotes properly.
I was able to solve my problem, but in a very forceful way by adding hard spaces in the proper place. Ugly, but it solves the problem.